# Are there existing paganini no. 1 caprices for piano?

Tags: piano, composition, violin

Liszt wrote famous Paganini Études for the piano, which consist of transcriptions of the Paganini caprices which are originally for the violin. For example, 'La Chasse', which is Liszt Étude

Liszt wrote famous transcriptions of the Paganini caprices for the piano, which were originally made for the violin: the Grandes Études de Paganini. For example, Paganini Caprice No. 9 "La Chasse" by Paganini (Paganini Étude No. 5 by Liszt), Paganini Caprice No. 24 by Paganini (Paganini Étude No. 6 by Liszt) and probably the most famous one: La Campanella. Now my question is, is there an existing transcription of the "Paganini Caprice No.1 by Paganini" for the piano? I haven't been able to find one, so I was wondering if you know an existing transcription which includes both the left hand and the right hand for the piano. If there are in fact none, does this have to do with the fact that it is actually impossible to play on the piano at the original tempo (95 BPM)

I looked up the Paganini Caprice No.1 for the violin and basically changed the instrument sound to piano, while keeping the tempo the same (Andante: 95 BPM). This only includes the right hand, so you can judge whether it is almost impossible to play or not.
https://musescore.com/user/28456830/scores/5696029

Comment: As a sidenote, there is also [Variations on a theme of Paganini](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variations_on_a_Theme_of_Paganini) by J. Brahms, which is based on Caprice no. 24. I don't know about no. 1 though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You somehow missed the [Paganini Étude No. 4 by Liszt](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jSIr-203n7o), which is a one-staff transcription of the Paganini Caprice No. 1. Enough additional notes are placed so some sections have to be played with both hands.

Comment: I looked up Liszt's earlier Etudes d'execution transcendante d'apres Paganini, and its versions of his 4th etude(/Paganini's Caprice No. 1) have even more elaborate left hand parts and an actual second staff.

Comment: Haha, I missed this. Thanks a lot! The transcendental etude seems more difficult, but fortunately it's slower.

Comment: You wrote that some sections have to be played by both hands. Look closer to the notation, look at the direction of the stems, and you can see that actually the whole piece is played by both hands.

Comment: @Dekkadeci FYI: the linked video is "private" and requires a login.